# How to clear blank below heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highchart HeatMap.I set 12 area on heatmap.
Like this.[image]
It have some blank below heatmap.
The heat map not fill on y-axis.
I want to  get this result.[image]
This is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Willie_LEE/68cfkb3r/3/).
I think that something occupies the space.
My Javascript codes:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        data: {
            csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
        },     
        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            height: 270,
            width: 360,
            margin: [0, 0,0, 0],
            events: {
                    load: function () {
                    this.renderer.rect(0, 0, 90,90 ).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(90,0, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(180,0 , 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(270,0, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(0, 90, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(90, 90, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(180, 90, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(270, 90, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(0, 180, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(90, 180, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(180, 180, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                    this.renderer.rect(270, 180, 90, 90).attr({
                        'stroke-width': 1,
                        stroke: 'red',
                        zIndex: 3
                    }).add();
                }                
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: undefined
        },
        xAxis: {
            visible: false,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
        },        
        yAxis: {
            visible: false,
            reversed: true,
        },
        colorAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0, '#000000'],
                [0.0208, '##000020'],
                [0.0416, '#000040'],
                [0.0624, '#000060'],
                [0.0832, '#000080'],
                [0.104, '#0000a0'],
                [0.1248, '#0000c0'],
                [0.1456, '#0000e0'],
                [0.1664, '#0000ff'],
                [0.1872, '#0020ff'],
                [0.208, '#0040ff'],
                [0.2288, '#0060ff'],
                [0.2496, '#0080ff'],
                [0.2704, '#00a0ff'],
                [0.2912, '#00c0ff'],
                [0.312, '#00e0ff'],
                [0.3328, '#00ffff'],
                [0.3536, '#00ffe0'],
                [0.3744, '#00ffc0'],
                [0.3952, '#00ffa0'],
                [0.416, '#00ff80'],
                [0.4368, '#00ff60'],
                [0.4576, '#00ff40'],
                [0.4784, '#00ff20'],
                [0.4992, '#00ff00'],
                [0.52, '#20ff00'],
                [0.5408, '#40ff00'],
                [0.5616, '#60ff00'],
                [0.5824, '#80ff00'],
                [0.6032, '#a0ff00'],
                [0.624, '#c0ff00'],
                [0.6448, '#e0ff00'],
                [0.6656, '#ffff00'],
                [0.6864, '#ffe000'],
                [0.7072, '#ffc000'],
                [0.728, '#ffa000'],
                [0.7488, '#ff8000'],
                [0.7696, '#ff6000'],
                [0.7904, '#ff4000'],
                [0.8112, '#ff2000'],
                [0.832, '#ff0000'],
                [0.8528, '#ff2020'],
                [0.8736, '#ff4040'],
                [0.8944, '#ff6060'],
                [0.9152, '#ff8080'],
                [0.936, '#ffa0a0'],
                [0.9568, '#ffc0c0'],
                [0.9776, '#ffe0e0'],
                [1, '#ffffff']
            ],
            labels: {
                format: '{value}℃'
            },
            visible: false
        },
                legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            roqsize: 500,
            clip: false,
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
                pointFormat: '{point.value} ℃</b>'
            },
            turboThreshold: 0
        }],
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        } 
    });
```

How can i clear it?
Please tell me what I should do?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` properties:

```
   yAxis: {
       ...,
       startOnTick: false,
       endOnTick: false
   },
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ta6o0cpk/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your margin and you will be able to fix it.

```
chart: { 
   margin: [0, 0,-2, 0]
}
```

Find the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shail_23/w5q3gfjb/) with the fix.

Comment: I know can Adjust  margin.
but why have this blank?

Comment: so you are looking to remove it without margin adjustment?

Comment: Yes. is that possible?

Comment: I am not sure but will try to dig more into this, for time being you can use margin. I'll update the answer once I found the fix.